# Extract text of certain font face from a docx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I am using python 3.4 along with `python-docx` library to work on `.docx` files. I have been able to extract text from the document. But my objective is to extract only those text with certain font (and modify them).

I have been searching for this in the [library documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for the past two days with no result.

Does anybody here have experience with this library, if so could they point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

At present, `python-docx` only has the ability to apply a font typeface using a style. You can detect runs having a particular style like this:

```
document = Document('having-fonts.docx')
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        if run.style == style_I_want:
            print run.text
```

If the special fonts are applied using a paragraph style you could use this:

```
document = Document('having-fonts.docx')
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style == style_I_want:
        print paragraph.text
```

If you can say more about the particulars I may be able to be more specific.

Comment: I tried this and find `run.style` gives `None` and `paragraph.style` gives `Normal` while I have bold and italic styles with different fonts in my file.
I want to extract text having `Preeti` font (a font used to display Devanagari script) and modify them.

Comment: It sounds like that formatting is applied directly to the text rather than by using a style. Unfortunately `python-docx` doesn't yet support reading directly applied formatting. If you want to add a feature request on the GitHub project we'll see about adding that capability.

Comment: I guess now I'll try some xml parsing. Could you please point me somewhere where I can read about this, specific to my problem?